# Python - Add lines in between a panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
index = [0,1,2,3,4,5]
s = pd.Series([1,1,1,2,2,2],index= index)
t = pd.Series([2007,2008,2011,2006,2007,2009],index= index)
f = pd.Series([2,4,6,8,10,12],index= index)
pp =pd.DataFrame(np.c_[s,t,f],columns = ["group","year","amount"])
pp

   group    year    amount
0   1       2007    2
1   1       2008    4
2   1       2011    6
3   2       2006    8
4   2       2007    10
5   2       2009    12
```

I want to add lines in between missing years for each group. My desire dataframe is like this:

```
   group    year    amount
0   1.0     2007    2.0
1   1.0     2008    4.0
2   1.0     2009    NaN
3   1.0     2010    NaN
4   1.0     2011    6
5   1.0     2006    8.0
6   2.0     2007    10.0
7   2.0     2008    NaN
8   2.0     2009    12.0
```

Is there any way to do it for a large dataframe?

Comment: Create a new df. Concatenate the two dfs and order by year should be enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First change year to datetime:

```
df.year = pd.to_datetime(df.year, format='%Y')
```

**`set_index`** with **`resample`**

```
df.set_index('year').groupby('group').amount.resample('Y').mean().reset_index()

   group       year  amount
0      1 2007-12-31     2.0
1      1 2008-12-31     4.0
2      1 2009-12-31     NaN
3      1 2010-12-31     NaN
4      1 2011-12-31     6.0
5      2 2006-12-31     8.0
6      2 2007-12-31    10.0
7      2 2008-12-31     NaN
8      2 2009-12-31    12.0
```